# Conversion problem

Tags: physics

A cereal box says "net weight 340 grams" What's the actual weight (a) in SI units and (b) in ounces?

What does net weight mean? Can I just go about this problem by simply converted the gram to SI units and ounces?

Answer (score 0):

Net weight means the weight of the *content* of the box, not including the box itself, or the plastic bag lining it, etc.

In order to get the "actual weight" of the entire item (assuming that means something different from the net weight), add how much the box weighs when empty.

Comment: How do I find out how much the empty box weighs? is there a formula?

Comment: @Lil: The easiest way would be to weigh it.